# VSTS How to add a new Issue work item to my Backlog?

Tags: azure-devops

I heard that you can add Issues to your Backlog, but I only get the option to create a new User Story or Bug. I googled a bit but haven't found the solution.

How do I activate Issues?

Comment: As far as I can tell this is currently not possible. You can craete an inherited process, disable the default "Issue" work item type, create a new "Problem" or "Impdiment" work item type and link that to the Requirements or Iteration backlog.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I figured it might be impossible since nobody in my Team knew anything about it, but now I can be sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently that's not possible.

You can create a custom work item in an inherited process and name it differently, copy over all the fields and layout and then add it to the backlog level you want it. But you will have to (temporarily) disable the existing WITD and will lose those from your visible list of work items.